# How to join two RDDs in spark with python?

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark

Suppose

```
rdd1 = ( (a, 1), (a, 2), (b, 1) ),
rdd2 = ( (a, ?), (a, *), (c, .) ).
```

Want to generate

```
( (a, (1, ?)), (a, (1, *)), (a, (2, ?)), (a, (2, *)) ).
```

Any easy methods?
I think it is different from the cross join but can't find a good solution.
My solution is

```
(rdd1
 .cartesian( rdd2 )
 .filter( lambda (k, v): k[0]==v[0] )
 .map( lambda (k, v): (k[0], (k[1], v[1])) ))
```

Comment: What you described is actually a natural join. Cross join is simply a Cartesian product.

Answer (score 14):

You are just looking for a simple join, e.g.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([("red",20),("red",30),("blue", 100)])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([("red",40),("red",50),("yellow", 10000)])
rdd.join(rdd2).collect()
# Gives [('red', (20, 40)), ('red', (20, 50)), ('red', (30, 40)), ('red', (30, 50))]
```